# Android failing to connect to my servlet

Tags: android, servlets

I am having trouble getting my android app connected to just *some particular* servlets running on my server. I am getting an `UnknownHostException` when trying to connect. I assure you I have used the

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

in my Manifest file and have already gone through atleast 5 or 6 similar SO questions.

When I use the URL which is shown with the original exception, in a browser, the servlet page shows up just fine. (Even in the device's browser!)

Note:

- I am running this on a physical device
- This happens only when I try and connect to some servlets. Not all. (Talk about weird!)

I'll give the codes if you want it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, this was a silly problem.

What I did was, I used just `http:/` instead of `http://` in front of the URL and when I pasted this in the browser, the browser auto-corrected it into `http://`. Changing that back to `http://` fixed it!

I leaving this here hoping that this might reduce the hours of headache caused by this annoying problem and help someone.